# Django: Category List - view's

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have model in models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nazwa Kategorii', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Odnośnik', unique=True, max_length=100)
    icon = models.ImageField('Ikonka Kategorii', upload_to='icons',
                              blank=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Kategoria"
        verbose_name_plural = "Kategorie"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And i want to do View with list of all Categories:
views.py

```
class CategoryList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Category
    context_object_name = 'category_list'
category_list = CategoryList.as_view()
```

In base.html i have:

```
{% for entry in category_list %}
<li><a href="#">{{ entry.name }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesent return any categories.
What i miss?
I want to add in basic template Menu with category list..

Comment: First of all Category model doesn't have title attribute. That might be the first reason why you don't see any results.

Comment: I know, wrong copy-pase :D But it still dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expect to have **category_list** context variable set for base.html. CategoryList class view uses template '< app_name >/category_list.html' by default. You can change this by setting **template_names** attribute for this view.

If you want to have 'category_list' context variable accessible in all templates (which is possible, taking into account that you try to use in base.html) you need to define [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and add this variable to the context.

Context processor you need can look like this:

```
def menu_processor(request):
    return {
        'category_list': Category.objects.all() 
    }
```

Once you have this function defined somewhere in your code (it is a good practive to put in in context_processors.py in related app) you need to register this in TEMPLATE_PROCESSORS settings variable (see above link to django docs for reference).

Last thing to mention here is that you should consider caching query results as this code will be exectued on each request.

Comment: So, can you explain me how to create menu in base.html?
Can I query for data and insert them where I want?